# Restore a PostgreSQL-9.6 database from an old complete dump and/or a up-to-date just base directory and other rescued files

Tags: postgresql, database-backups, recovery

I'm trying to restore/rescue a database from some that I have:

- I have all the recent files in `PGDATA/base` (`/var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main/base/`), but I have not the complete `/var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main/`
- I have all files from an old backup (and not much different) dump that I restored in a new installation of PostgreSQL-9.6.
- I have a lot of rescued files from the hard drive (from `ddrescue`) and I got thousand of files without a name (having a "#" and then a number instead and in lost+found directory), so, for instance:

  - I have the `pg_class` file
  - I have the `pg_clog` directory with `0000` file

**Edit:**

Probably I have the content of `pg_xlog`, but I don't have the name of the files. I have 5 files sized 16777216 bytes:

```
#288294 (date 2019-04-01)
#288287 (date 2019-05-14)
#288293 (date 2019-07-02)
#261307 (date 2019-11-27)
#270185 (date 2020-01-28)
```

Also my old dump is from 2019-04-23, so the first one could
be the same?

So my next step is going to try to read those files with `pg_xlogdump`
and/or trying to name them with those namefiles (beginning with
`00000001000000000000000A` by date and put them to the new one `pg_xlog` directory, that I saw that the system filenaming them, could be?). Also I realized that the last one has the date of the day hard drive crashed, so I have the last one.

The `PGDATA/base` directory  I rescued from the hard drive (damaged) contains directories `1`, `12406`, `12407` and `37972` with a lot of files inside. I check with `pg_filedump -fi` that my updated data is stored on files in directory `37972`.

Same (but old) data is stored in files in directory `PGDATA/base/16387` in the restored dump.

I tried directly to copy the files from one to other mixing the updated data over the old database but it doesn't work. After solved permission errors I can go in to the "Frankenstein" database in that way:

```
 postgres@host:~$ postgres --single -P -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main/ dbname
```

And I tried to do something, like reindex, and I get this error:

```
PostgreSQL stand-alone backend 9.6.16
backend> reindex system dbname;
ERROR:  could not access status of transaction 136889
DETAIL:  Could not read from file "pg_subtrans/0002" at offset 16384: Success.
CONTEXT:  while checking uniqueness of tuple (1,7) in relation "pg_toast_2619"
STATEMENT:  reindex system dbname;
```

Certainly `pg_subtrans/0002` file is part of the "Frankenstein" and not the good one (because I didn't find it yet, not with that name), so I tried: to copied another one that seems similar first and then, to generate 8192 zeroes with `dd` to that file, in both cases I get the same error (and in case that the file doesn't exist get the `DETAIL:  Could not open file "pg_subtrans/0002": No such file or directory.`). Anyway I have not idea that what should be that file. Do you think could I get that data from other file? Or could I find the missing file using some tool? So `pg_filedump` show me empty for the other file in that directory `pg_subtrans/0000`.

**Extra note:** I found this useful blog post that talk about restore from just rescued files using `pg_filedump`, `pg_class`'s file, `reindex system` and other tools and but is so hard for me to understand how to adapt it to my concrete and easier problem (I think that my problem is easier because I have a dump): https://www.commandprompt.com/blog/recovering_a_lost-and-found_database/

Comment: "but it doesn't work" what error did you get?

Comment: "I get the databases directory using ddrescue and I got thousand of files without a name (having a number instead and in lost+found directory)".  The kind of numbers PostgreSQL usually calls it files, or something else assigned by the rescue operation?

Comment: Error is permission denied, numbers are assigned by the rescue operation (I edited those data in my question). Thanks.

Comment: "but I gave that those files the permissions for postgres with chown -R postgres:postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main/base" What about the entire path down to that point?  Who are doing this as?  Your overall problem seems pretty grim, and you might want to hire a firm that specializes in doing this, but this particular problem seems well defined and solvable.

Comment: You was very right with permissions issue. I go a step behind. I edited in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally we restored completely database based on `PGDATA/base/37972` directory after 4 parts:

1. Checking and "greping" with `pg_filedump -fi` which file correspond
   to each table. To "greping" easier we made a script.

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   for filename in ./*; do
       echo "$filename"
       pg_filedump -fi "$filename"|grep "$1"
   done
   ```

   *NOTE: Only useful with small strings.*
2. Executing the great tool `pg_filedump -D`. `-D` is a new option (from `postgresql-filedump` version ≥10), to decode tuples using given comma separated list of types.

   As we know types because we made the database, we "just" need to give a comma separated list of types related to the table. I wrote "just" because in some cases it could be a little bit complicated. One of our tables need this kind of command:

`pg_filedump -D text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,timestamp,text,text,text,text,int,text,text,int,text,int,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,text,int,int 38246 | grep COPY > restored_table1.txt`

From `pg_filedump -D` manual:

Supported types:

- bigint
- bigserial
- bool
- char
- charN     -- char(n)
- date
- float
- float4
- float8
- int
- json
- macaddr
- name
- oid
- real
- serial
- smallint
- smallserial
- text
- time
- timestamp
- timetz
- uuid
- varchar
- varcharN -- varchar(n)
- xid
- xml
- ~        -- ignores all attributes left in a tuple

  All those `text` for us were type character varying(255) but `varcharN` didn't work for us, so after other tests we finally change it for `text`.

  `timestamp` for us was type timestamp with time zone but `timetz` didn't work for us, so after other tests we finally change it for `timestamp` and we opted to lose the time zone data.

  This changes work perfect for this table.

  Other tables were much easier:

  `pg_filedump -D int,date,int,text 38183 | grep COPY > restored_table2.txt`

3. As we get just "raw" data we have to re-format to CSV format. So we made a python program for [format from `pg_filedump -D` output to CSV](https://gitlab.com/CommonsVisualization/databases_of_the_commons/-/blob/master/pg_filedump2CSV.py).
4. We inserted each CSV to the PostgreSQL (after create each empty table again):

   ```
   COPY scheme."table2"(id_comentari,id_observacio,text,data,id_usuari,text_old) 
   FROM '<path>/table2.csv' DELIMITER '|' CSV HEADER;
   ```

I hope this will help other people :)

Answer (score -1):

That is doomed. Without the information in `pg_xlog` and (particularly) `pg_clog`, you cannot get the information back.

A knowledgeable forensics expert might be able to salvage some of your data, but it is not a straightforward process.

Comment: Maybe I have information in `pg_xlog` and `pg_clog`. `ddrescue` give thounsands of rescued files. I found data with `pg_filedump` through trial and error. How could I find in thouse rescued files `pg_xlog` and `pg_clog`? Thanks.

Comment: Hire an expert who knows the ins and outs of PostgreSQL.

Comment: I saw that in my restored from backup installation `pg_clog` only has the file `0000`. And I found it in `lost+found`. What should I do it with it? I'm still searching for content in directory `pg_xlog`.

Comment: Perhaps your original `pg_clog` only had `0000`, perhaps it had more files. These data determine which row versions are visible and which are not.

Comment: I found 5 files that are [at least part of] the content of `pg_xlog` directory. I updated the question.

Comment: Still, you will need an expert there.

Comment: When I ask this in a Questions&Answers site is because I want to learn how to solve it for myself. So: what would be next step that an expert would try in that case?

Comment: That is too complicated to explain. It depends on what exactly you have got there. Poke around in the innards and source of PostgreSQL for a couple of years, then you will be on your way.